# Dell M2800 Ubuntu 21.10 Graphics Help W4170M

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, radeon, amdgpu

I have a M2800 with FirePro W4170M. Ubuntu is showing this as Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD®/ATI] Mars XTX [Radeon HD 8790M] (FirePro W4170M) / Intel® HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)

[System Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruCex.png)

[lshw info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShG75.png)

When I run DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears I get the below errors.

[glxgears error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9YDK.png)

Not sure if I need to install the AMDGPU drivers or need to tweak some other settings.

glxgears work fine without DRI_PRIME=1.

Any help is appreciated. I want 4170M to be primary card.